# What can cause Felyne Explorer not to work?

Tags: monster-hunter-generations

I just ate for Felyne Explorer, which should always make me spawn in the map's secret area, but after departing, I found myself at base camp.

This was a High Rank quest in the Verdant Hills, what's going on?

Comment: If a quest makes you start in base camp (such as Harvest Tours), then Explorer won't activate.  Do you remember which quest specifically?  I can try as well.

Comment: @mmatthews I don't remember which quest, but everyone spawned in random locations.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure you actually had Felyne Explorer activate? Sometimes after eating you don't get the skills you want.

You can increase the chance that the skills selected will actually activate by eating food where the chef is "fired up", or by using a Voucher. To guarantee that you'll receive these skills, use a Gourmet Voucher.

Comment: Yes, I had it in my active skills.